# Can the `verbatim` environment be used inside a custom environment definition?

Tags: environments, verbatim

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\newenvironment{abc}
{\begin{verbatim}}
{\end{verbatim}}

\begin{document}

% This works.
\begin{verbatim}
abc
\end{verbatim}

% This does not work.
\begin{abc}
abc
\end{abc}

\end{document}
```

I am trying to create a custom environment that uses `verbatim`. But the above code does not work. How should I do this?

Comment: It mostly depends on what you want the custom environment to do. Look at `fancyvrb` and `tcolorbox` before reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on the verbatim environment in question.

## Environment `verbatim` of package `verbatim`

If you load package `verbatim`, then its environment `verbatim` can be used inside other environment definitions as long it is not hidden inside other groups. Also, it cannot be used as `\begin{verbatim}`, because `verbatim` needs to know the name of the parent environment to find the end tag `\end{<parent>}`. The parent environment name would be overwritten by the LaTeX code for `\begin`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{verbatim}

\newenvironment{abc}
{\verbatim}
{\endverbatim}

\begin{document}

% This works.
\begin{verbatim}
abc
\end{verbatim}

% This does now work.
\begin{abc}
abc
\end{abc}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

## Package `fancyvrb`

Custom verbatim environments can be created by
`\DefineVerbatimEnvironment`, example from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyvrb/fancyvrb.pdf), slightly modified:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\DefineVerbatimEnvironment{abc}{Verbatim}{%
  gobble=2,
  numbers=left,
  numbersep=2mm,
  frame=lines,
  framerule=0.8mm,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{abc}
  First verbatim line.
  Second verbatim line.
\end{abc}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result fancyvrb]

## Package `listings`

Environments can be defined with `\lstnewenvironment`. Example from the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{pascal}{%
  \lstset{language=pascal}%
}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{pascal}
for i:=maxint to 0 do
begin
     { do nothing }
end;
\end{pascal}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result listings]